# Grails fileUpload limit

Tags: file, grails, upload

I to be able to limit the file upload size for my website. Here is my code:

```
 def p = request.getFile('as')
        if(!a.empty) {
            a.transferTo( new File(abass) )
            response.sendError(200,'Done')
```

Is there a way to do it programmatically, or do I need to change something in a Grails config file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I *think* you should be able to use the following, convert it to the resources.groovy DSL format, and it should work...

```
<bean id="multipartResolver"> 
    <property name="maxUploadSize"> 
         <value>xxxxxxxx</value> 
    </property> 
</bean>
```

Comment: surely you need to specify the class of the bean?

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the [file uploader plugin](http://www.grails.org/plugin/file-uploader). It makes it easy to configure the max size and type of upload among other things.