# Grails, Limiting file upload size to few Megabytes

Tags: spring, apache, tomcat, grails, file-upload

I'm trying to find a way to limit the size of a file a user can upload. I need to satisfy the followings:

-I can use client side file size detection but that can be bypassed. So server side is more preferable. 
-I want to be able to figure out the file size before the upload starts, or if that is not possible, I should be able to set a limit on the size while streaming, so if the stream reaches the limit it stops and doesn't receive the stream from the client anymore. (I saw that Apache has a max limit that I can use, but I was wondering if I can use Spring/Grails to do that)

Is there a way to do this elegantly in Grails ?

P.S: I noticed that "multipartResolver" can set a limit on file uploads, does multipartResolver uploads first and then check or does it check the size before the actual full download of the file ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13853094/29995 may work for you, but I've not used it, so not sure.

Comment: Thanks for sharing, I tried that but I am planning to use my own code for uploading.

Answer (score 0):

Knowing that you are using your own code for uploading, I am assuming that you have a field in your domain that will save the file. If so, then you could just add a maxSize property in the static constrains of the domain class.

example:

```
class Files {

  byte[] uploadedFile


static constraints = {
uploadedFile(nullable:true, maxSize: 10 * 1024 * 1024)

}
}
```

It has worked for me. I hope it helps.

Comment: I appreciate you offering a solution, but I want to save it into a file system, I don't use database.

Answer (score 0):

I already answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6603681/grails-fileupload-limit) regarding the size of the file.  This would be a good use if you are storing the file on a file system rather than as a blob in the database.  I do not know when the size of file is checked.

I would assume it would only be able to do this after the file has been fully uploaded.  I don't see how you could detect it while streaming as the server won't have all the bytes to calculate the size.

JavaScript cannot detect the size of a file before upload.  If you would want to do this client side you would have to look into a flash type solution.

Answer (score 0):

Apache Tomcat allows for the following configuration, In hard-coded or Annotation format. I'm not sure if the max-file-size is calculated during the upload process or after the file is uploaded to a temp place. The documentation indicates the followings :

> The @MultipartConfig annotation supports the following optional
>   attributes:
>
> location: An absolute path to a directory on the file system. The
>   location attribute does not support a path relative to the application
>   context. This location is used to store files temporarily while the
>   parts are processed or when the size of the file exceeds the specified
>   fileSizeThreshold setting. The default location is "".
>
> fileSizeThreshold: The file size in bytes after which the file will be
>   temporarily stored on disk. The default size is 0 bytes.
>
> MaxFileSize: The maximum size allowed for uploaded files, in bytes. If
>   the size of any uploaded file is greater than this size, the web
>   container will throw an exception (IllegalStateException). The default
>   size is unlimited.
>
> maxRequestSize: The maximum size allowed for a multipart/form-data
>   request, in bytes. The web container will throw an exception if the
>   overall size of all uploaded files exceeds this threshold. The default
>   size is unlimited.

annotation approach :

```
@MultipartConfig(location="/tmp", fileSizeThreshold=1024*1024, 
    maxFileSize=1024*1024*5, maxRequestSize=1024*1024*5*5)
```

and here is the hard-coded value:

```
<multipart-config>
<!– 50MB max –>
<max-file-size>52428800</max-file-size>
<max-request-size>52428800</max-request-size>
<file-size-threshold>0</file-size-threshold>
</multipart-config>
```

I appreciate it if anyone can clarify if the MaxFileSize is calculated during the upload process.